# Find the remaining area when a half sphere is put in a cylinder.

Tags: geometry

[image: figure]

Find the volume of the area $FDG+GCE$.

Please see the picture before seeing my further work.

Say, the volume to be determined is $V$.

So,

$$
\begin{align}
V &= \text{(Volume of the cylinder FECD) - volume of the half sphere} \\
%
  &= \pi \left( \frac{r}{2} \right)^2 \times 2r -  \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 \\
&\text{(here, the radius of the cylinder is $r/2$ and the height of the cylinder is $2r$)} \\
%
 &= \frac{1}{2} \pi r^3 - \frac{2}{3} \pi r^3
\end{align}
$$
 which gives me a negative result. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

In your figure, the radius of the cylinder is $r$, not $r/2$ and the height is $r$. So your cylinder volume is twice what you had written, namely $\pi r^3$. And now your result is positive.

Comment: Actually this math is a part of a prove of a physics equation and from where I was studying, the writer did the same thing as you stated. But I had no clue how. That's why I asked this question with the description of my concept. So can you please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, the radius of the sphere is bigger than the radius of the cylinder.
[image]

Comment: Yes your figure is quite the practical form that i was trying to depict. But how do we find the remaining space inside the cylinder then? Volume can't be negative.

Comment: @Sami, The volume became negative because you subtracted the volume of the semi sphere which is larger than the volume of the cylinder.

Comment: Ok now I get it. With a cylinder of radius r/2 I can never fit in a semi sphere of radius r. So the radius of the cylinder must be "r" at least as Mark said. Thanks.